# How to echo checkbox group with multidimentional array

Tags: php, checkbox

I need help to get the data from my checkbox-group with multidimensional array options to reflect in my post page(single.php code). Radio type is working well but the checkbox-group type is not. I added on the bottom the sample code found in my single.php for the radio type which query the data to my post page for your reference.

Here's the array from my metabox.php code:

```
<?php
// array
$prefix = 'wtf_';
$meta_box = array( 'id' => 'site',
               'title' => 'Program Details',
               'page' => 'post',
               'context' => 'normal',
               'priority' => 'high',
               'fields' => array(
                        array('name' => 'Principal Return',
                                'desc' => 'Principal Return After Expiry or Not',
                                'id' => $prefix . 'principal',
                                'type' => 'radio',
                                'options' => array(
                                        array('name' => '  Yes    ', 'value' => 'Yes-after expiry'),
                                        array('name' => '  No    ', 'value' => 'No-included on the interest')
                                    )
                                ),
                        array(
                        'name' => 'Compounding',
                        'desc' => 'Choose if compounding is allowed or not',
                        'id' => $prefix . 'compounding',
                        'type' => 'radio',
                        'options' => array(
                             array('name' => '  Yes    ', 'value' => 'Allowed'),
                             array('name' => '  No    ', 'value' => 'Not Allowed'),
                             array('name' => '  Re-purchase', 'value' => 'Yes thru re-purchase')
                    )
                                ),
                             array ('name' => 'Payment Processors',  
                                    'desc'  => 'Payment Processsor Accepted',  
                                    'id'    => $prefix.'processors',  
                                    'type'  => 'checkbox_group',  
                                    'options' => array(
                                                    array('label' => ' Liberty Reserve ', 'value' =>'LR'),
                                                    array('label' => ' SolidTrustPay ', 'value' =>'STP'),
                                                    array('label' => ' EgoPay ', 'value' =>'EgoPay'),
                                                    array('label' => ' Perfect Money ', 'value' =>'PM'),
                                                    array('label' => ' Payza ', 'value' =>'Payza'),
                                                    array('label' => ' PayPal ', 'value' =>'PayPal'),
                                                    array('label' => ' Bankwire ', 'value' =>'Bankwire')
                                      ))))

// Callback function to show fields in meta box
function mytheme_show_box() {
global $meta_box, $post;

// Use nonce for verification
echo '<input type="hidden" name="mytheme_meta_box_nonce" value="',    wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';

echo '<table class="form-table">';

foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
    // get current post meta data
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

    echo '<tr>',
            '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
            '<td>';
    switch ($field['type']) {
    case 'text':
                echo $statetemt;
            break;
        case 'textarea':
                echo $statetemt;
            break;
        case 'select':
                echo $statetemt;
            break;
        case 'radio':
            foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                echo $statetemt; }
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
            foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                echo $statetemt;}
            break;
        case 'checkbox_group':  
             foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {  
                echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$option['value'].'" name="'.$field['id'].'[]" id="'.$option['value'].'"',$meta && in_array($option['value'], $meta) ? ' checked="checked"' : '',' />',$option['label']; }  
                echo '<br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
            break;
    }


//From my single.php code  <<<<=================

<div class="sdinfo"><strong>Principal Return</strong>:<span><?php $principal = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wtf_principal', true); 
      if (isset($principal[0])) { 
        echo $principal ; 
} else if (isset($principal[1])) {
        $principal = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wtf_principal', true);
        echo $principal; 
       } else {_e('Not Available');} ?></span></div>
<div class="sdinfo"><strong>Program Started</strong>:<span> <?php $started = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wtf_started', true); if (isset($started[0])) { echo $started; 
                } else {_e('Not Available');} ?></span></div>
<div class="sdinfo"><strong>Compounding</strong>:<span>
<?php $compounding = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wtf_compounding', true); 
      if (isset($compounding[0])) { 
        echo $compounding ; 
                } else if (isset($compounding[1])) {
        $compounding = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wtf_compounding', true);
        echo $compounding; 
      } else if (isset($compounding[2])) {
        $compounding = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wtf_compounding', true);
        echo $compounding; 
      } else {_e('Not Available');} ?></span></div>
?>
```

This give me an output from post meta like this:
[admin screenshot](http://i46.tinypic.com/nlvt60.jpg)

This is the output from my post page. :
[post page screenshot](http://i47.tinypic.com/10pde34.jpg)

Please help!.. I am not a programmer hope you can share me an answer in much details.Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://php.net/foreach  will get you started.

Comment: That's nice that you **need** to have an output... [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? Anything specific where things don't work as expected?

Comment: I already updated my question for clarity..hope you can share your answer.

Answer (score 0):

All what you need is point an array using `var_dump($array)` to check where and what data you need from arrays fields.

Second you need to get `foreach()` function. For example you want grab an array of data:

`'priority' => 'high',` should be as example:

`echo $meta_box["priority"]` which will result as value of array: `high`

If you are not sure and not familiar with array use as simple:

```
foreach ($meta_box as $arr)
{
    var_dump($arr);

    #then play and manipulate how to grab a fields a data:
    foreach ($arr["fields"][""] as $fa)
    {
        var_dump($fa["name"]);
        var_dump($fa["desc"]);
        var_dump($fa["desc"]);
    }

    #...
}
```

Learn how to grab via `var_dump()` if you unsure with array of data.

Payment Processors     LR STP EgoP

```
echo $meta_box["fields"][""]["name"];
```

Than you need grab a data of an array:

```
foreach ($meta_box["fields"][""]["options"] as $options)
{
    foreach ($options as $options_key)
    {
        foreach ($options_key as $opt_val)
        {
            $result .= ' '.$opt_val;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Marin,thanks for you answer much appreciated but still I can not figure out with your answer.I updated my question to have clarity of what i want.also attached the screenshots link.